# Get value of textarea created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, database, jsp

Hey I have a textarea that is automatically updated every time I hit enter with the response from a Google api, but when i try to take the value from that textarea it returns null . I know that the jsp script runs only one time and I don't know how to run every time the text from the text area is changed.

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="input-field" id="input">
                    <input placeholder="Hey, ask me something..." id="q" 
                        type="text" type="email" class="form-control"                 
                        onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) actionApi();">
                </div>
                <div id="result"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col s5">
                <h5>Response payload:</h5>

                <h1 id="test"></h1>
                <textarea id="jsonResponse" name="parametru">
                <%
                        Connection conn = null;
                        try {
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/api?user=root&password=1234");
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String res = request.getParameter("parametru");
                        out.println(res);

                        try (PreparedStatement insert = (PreparedStatement) conn
                                .prepareStatement("insert into test(Id, nume) value(default, ?)")) {
                            if (res != null)
                                insert.setString(1, res);
                            else
                                insert.setString(1, "aaa");
                            insert.execute();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    %>
                    </textarea>


                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the script that updates the textarea is this

```
<script>
    function actionApi() {
        setTimeout(
                function() {
                    var node = document.getElementsByClassName("raspuns")[document
                            .getElementsByClassName("raspuns").length - 1];
                    textContent = node.textContent;
                    document.getElementById("jsonResponse").innerHTML = textContent;
                    console.log(textContent);
                }, 1500);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update textarea value using `.value`:

```
document.getElementById("jsonResponse").value = textContent;
```

Comment: It updates the value, but when i try to take that value bake it returns null, because what is inside <% AND %> run only one time and this is when i reload the page